# QGIS Function Editor/ Python question

Tags: qgis, python

I'm currently using the layer_property(*layerName*,'source') to produce a list of copyright statements for the Print Composer by putting that in an if() statement.

However, that isn't very flexible as it would need hardcoding for every layer and it wouldn't have checks to see if the copyright had already been printed for a previous layer.

The obvious solution is to put this into the function editor, but I can't find anything that would work in python/ function editor to pull the file path out.